# How to notify my server that a new docker image has been published in my CI/CD line?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, cicd

I have accomplished these steps in my GitHub Actions (CI/CD) till here:

- Pulling the required repositories
- Installing the necessary environment
- Installing dependencies
- Building a docker image (multi-stage build)
- Pushing my container to my personal container repository

However, since I'm using a VPS, I need to notify my server to understand that a new version of my image is published.

I'm stuck at this stage.

I have two questions:

1. How can I make this stage automatic. In other words, how can I make my VPS know that it has to pull the new version of the image?
2. Should I stop my docker container on my VPS before pulling the image? What is the process here? Does docker gracefully upgrades the image without downtime?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for devops.SE. And including how you've deployed the container will make a big difference (is this in kubernetes, do you have a github self-hosted runner, etc).

Comment: See one way of doing this: https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Comment: How did you eventually solve this?

Comment: @Ionix, I have not solved it yet. I manually go to the VPS and pull the image.